# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'model'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

There is many questions from the same object. But mine is little different. The difference is that in my problem i am NOT using any Backbone model only backbone view.

I am using only Backbone View. and the following is the error stack when i initialise the view.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'model' in ace-edit-spec-examples-1-8
(anonymous function) underscore.js:783
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
_.pick underscore.js:782
_.extend._configure backbone.js:1086
Backbone.View backbone.js:983
child backbone.js:1529
Backbone.View.extend.render itemview.js:90
Backbone.View.extend.addListItem listview.js:99
Backbone.View.extend.renderList listview.js:84
(anonymous function) listview.js:42
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
Backbone.View.extend.render listview.js:41
Backbone.View.extend.render tabview.js:124
(anonymous function) tabview.js:50
collection.fetch.success util.js:28
options.success backbone.js:854
fire jquery.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery.js:1148
done jquery.js:8074
callback
```

Any help?

EDIT :

my view

```
var AceEditorView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (id,type,here) {
          this.id = id;
          this.type = type;
          this.here = here;
          //this.render();
        }});
```

my  call :

```
new AceEditorView('ace-edit-spec-examples-1-'+json.id,'json',this);
```

Comment: Please share the code for your view and the function that creates it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature for [`Backbone.View.constructor` / `Backbone.View.initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) is `new View([options])`, so you have to pass your parameters as a hash of options. Try

```
var AceEditorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (opts) {
      this.id = opts.id;
      this.type = opts.type;
      this.here = opts.here;
    }
});
```

and instantiate it as

```
new AceEditorView({
    id: 'ace-edit-spec-examples-1-'+json.id,
    type: 'json',
    here: this
});
```

Comment: I found that passing the parameters not as a hash works in dev, but once you compress it with require then I get the error the OP mentions.